# Remove last two characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code to go through a loop and if it finds "gb" in a cell i want to delete the last two characters in that cell.

Here is the loop

```
Sub RemoveUnits()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim x As Long
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        w = r.Value
        If InStr(w, "gb") > 0 Then
            [INSERT CODE HERE]
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

The bit i am stuck on is the code that removes the last two characters. I know it should go within this if statement but all the answers I have found online do not seem to work.

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple [Mid()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php) function

```
r = Mid$(r, 1, len(r)-2)
```

or [Left()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php)

```
r = Left$(r, len(r)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by vba4all but with small check. It's always a good practice when using Mid or substring to check for the length :)

```
r = IIf(Len(r) > 2, Mid(r, 1, Len(r) - 2), r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find that use `AutoFilter`, `Find` or a variant will greatly speed up working with the range. Something like below.

```
   Sub RemoveUnits()
    Dim X
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    X = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X)
        For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
          If InStr(X(lngRow, lngCol), "gb", vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then X(lngRow, lngCol) = Left$(X(lngRow, lngCol), Len(X(lngRow, lngCol)) - 2)
        Next
    Next
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2 = X
   End Sub
```